# PHP5-FPM - Access Denied after Update

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i updatet my PHP5 FPM to PHP 5.4.42-1~dotdeb+7.4. But after that i become now the error Message

```
 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/mysite/index.html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream
```

So i checked my php5-fpm vhost conf, all security extensions for HTML are already there,- i checked the www.conf of php and they are also included 
(security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .htm .html)

In my Serverblock i use

```
location ~ \.(htm|html)$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I really have no idea whats suddenly wrong with him

Comment: Okay can be closed is now fixed. In my vhost config i had this here for unknown reason (But that worked before the latest update)  Wrong: `php_admin_value[security.limit_extensions] = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .htm .html` correctly: `security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .htm .html`

Comment: I think the `php_admin_value...` is the .htaccess notation of setting PHP values. The .conf file should not have this syntax.

Also, it is better to add your answer yourself and accept it or edit your question (instead of indicating your resolution in comments)